# Error adding web reference to project

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-reference

I need to add web reference to ASP.NET project, but unfortunately I got error:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://isapi.somehost.com/soapclient/soapclient.php?URL=http://isapi.mekashron.com/SmartHD/MekashronTV.dll%2Fwsdl%2FISmartHD/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
object(SoapFault)#3 (9) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  strin
```

Is there any ways to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the exact exception you got to help you further. 
But couple of initial thoughts.

1. ASP.NEt is not able to get the WSDL to generate a proxy class. You ight need to check permissions.
2. If it is WCF service try to add service reference.

Thanks

Comment: You should post this as comment and not as an answer

Comment: Hi, in fact that's complete exception message, nothing else I got.

Comment: When I'm trying to add this as service reference (not web reference) - I got 404 error.

Comment: in that case, the uri is not correct. try to browse the url in the browser and see whether you are able to access the service.

Comment: Yes, it can be reached from browser

Comment: when i tried browsing the same got 404..this is the url i tried http://http://isapi.mekashron.com/SmartHD/MekashronTV.dll/wsdl/ISmartHD/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata   chec

Comment: Ok, what is this can be? What's wrong with this web service?